# Smooth scrolling not smooth scrolling (Inline CSS)

Tags: html, css, inline

I want to add the smooth scrolling effect so users can go straight to the bottom of the page to fill out a form. I need to add the smooth scrolling effect using inline CSS. I used the code below but I'm not sure why is not working?

```css
/* added by edito for visualization purpose */
a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 400vh;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#quick-contact" style="scroll-behavior: smooth;">REGISTER NOW</a>

  <div id="quick-contact" class="quick-contact pad-bottom-30">
    <h4>REGISTER NOW</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `scroll-bahvior: smooth` needs to bet applied to the scrollign element which by default would be `html`

Comment: @tacoshy is correct. https://jsfiddle.net/t7rugw3z/1/

Comment: @tacoshy it all needs to be inline

Comment: then add it inline to the html tag...

Answer (score 0):

`scroll-behavior: smooth` needs to bet applied to the scrolling element which by default would be `html`:

```css
/* added by edito for visualization purpose */
a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 400vh;
}
```

```html
<html style="scroll-behavior: smooth;">

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="#quick-contact">REGISTER NOW</a>

    <div id="quick-contact" class="quick-contact pad-bottom-30">
      <h4>REGISTER NOW</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the latest `scrollIntoView()` or `scrollTo()` function using JavaScript. You can check [MDN Doc][1]s, because `scroll-behavior:smooth` doesn't have all browser support plus we can't make customisations.

**LOGIC YOU NEED :**.

```js
let link = document.querySelector('a');
let targetElement = document.querySelector(".quick-contact");
link.addEventListener('click', function(){
   targetElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
});
```

**MAKE THE FOLLING CHANGES IN HTML AND TRY THIS, CODE, I FIND IT THE SIMPLEST**

```js
let link = document.querySelector('.link');
let targetElement = document.querySelector(".quick-contact");

link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   targetElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
});
```

```css
    .main {
      height:290vh;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      justify-content:space-between;
    }

    a {
      flex:1;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="main">
      <a href="#" class="link">REGISTER NOW</a>

      <div class="quick-contact pad-bottom-30">
        <h4>REGISTER NOW</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```